# Как создать суперпользователя (superuser) в postgresql?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

Уважаемые знатоки postgresql!

После вот такой команды:

```
db=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ext WITH SCHEMA test;
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "ext"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Вопрос: как создать суперпользователя из уже существующего пользователя?

Comment: А точно нужны права суперпользователя? документация рекомендует иное: _**Tip:** It is good practice to create a role that has the_ CREATEDB _and_ CREATEROLE _privileges, but is not a superuser, and then use this role for all routine management of databases and roles. This approach avoids the dangers of operating as a superuser for tasks that do not really require it._

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо выполнить следующее:

`ALTER USER user WITH SUPERUSER;`

Вместо `user` имя вашего пользователя соответственно.

Comment: тут еще нужно добавить, что делать это нужно из-под суперпользователя, типа postgres